# cannot import name 'TFLiteConverter'?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using Colab (Tensorflow version 1.15.0, and Python 3 notebook) to import TFLiteConverter using the following code:

```
from tensorflow.lite import TFLiteConverter

converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('/drive/My Drive/FSD_modelV09A.h5')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("/drive/My Drive/FSD_modelV09A.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

and this error happened:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TFLiteConverter'
```

I'm referring this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#class_tfliteconverter)

Comment: Replace `lite.TFLiteConverter.` with `TFLiteConverter.` as you have imported the class from the `tensorflow.lite` module.

Comment: You mean replace that line into this, right?

`converter = TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('/drive/My Drive/FSD_modelV09A.h5')`

It still gives the same error though.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tensorflow import lite

converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('/drive/My Drive/FSD_modelV09A.h5')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("/drive/My Drive/FSD_modelV09A.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

This should work.